# Print the entire content of a scrollable table

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, printing

I have following page to get printed which has horizontal scrolling. I need to print content within the horizontal scroll bar area.

[image: content to be printed]

When this page is printed, I get an output which does not contain all the fields in the horizontal scroll bar area.

[image]

Not all the content within the scroll bar is printed.

The method I am using is Print CSS.

```
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display: none;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print CSS you’ve got there will hide any HTML with a class of `noprint`.

Could you show us an outline of the HTML of the scrolling area, and the regular CSS applied to it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. This is what I did:

```
@media print {
    .noprint { 
        display: none
    }
    .mypages div.compare {
        white-space: normal
    }

    .mypages .compare .estate {
        padding-bottom: 110px
    }
}
```

Here, div `.compare` is the container which contains the all the elements that I want to print.

and `.estate` is the one state I want to print in the list of divs. it is used to set the gap between printed elements. Which means that it print 3 states in a row. Then second 3 in the bottom of first and like wise. To set the gap between these rows, I have used `.mypages .compare .estate` div.